# Search in struct, delivering index of array?

Tags: swift, search, indexing, struct, find

What's needed to get this code running?
Hi, I already have this part of code. It searches in an array of struct and delivers - if found - the index of that item:

```
    for index in 0 ..< gSteering.count {
        if gSteering[index].Ext == fileExtension.uppercaseString {
            priority = index
            break
        }
    }
```

I'm sure, that there is are shoreter and more elegant way in SWIFT using library functions. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
let priority = gSteering.indexOf() {
    $0.Ext == fileExtension.uppercaseString
}
```

P.S. And if you want priority to default to maxint in case if item is not found:

```
let priority = gSteering.indexOf() {
    $0.Ext == fileExtension.uppercaseString
} ?? Int.max
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that indexOf is only part of 2.0. I still use XCode 6.3.2. I think I will change when moving to 7.0.

Comment: In Swift 1.2 you can try using this: `let priority = find(gSteering, fileExtension.uppercaseString) ?? Int.max`

Comment: I get the error:

'(C.Index?, Int)' is not convertable to 'Equatable'

So I added:

func ==(l: Steering, r: Steering) -> Bool {
    return l.Ext == r.Ext
}

But this doesn't make sense to me. :-(  And of course it didn't work.

Steering is the name of the struct type.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this `.Ext` thing.  Can you try this: `find(lazy(a).map({ $0.Ext }), fileExtension.uppercaseString) ?? Int.max`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I could come up with:

```
if let index = (gSteering.map{ $0.Ext }).indexOf(fileExtension.uppercaseString) 
{ 
    priority = index
}
else 
{
    // Not found.
}
```

And here's another one:

```
let priority = gSteering.indexOf { $0.Ext == fileExtension.uppercaseString }
```

And here's one to get the object directly instead of the index:

```
// This will give you an array with all the results that match.
let priorityObj = gSteering.filter { $0.Ext == fileExtension.uppercaseString }
```